# contentPauseRequested in Video Suite Inspector

Tags: javascript, html, adsense, vast, advertisement-server

I have a problem.

I have VPAID JS creations .
Here's Vast Tag

```
    <VAST xmlns:MM="http://api.mediamind.com/V1/DataContracts" version="2.0">
<Ad id="10724976">
<InLine>
<AdSystem>
<![CDATA[ MediaMind ]]>
</AdSystem>
<AdTitle>
<![CDATA[ html5_new_ad ]]>
</AdTitle>
<Description>
<![CDATA[ html5_new_ad ]]>
</Description>
<Impression id="Impression">
<![CDATA[
http://go.idmnet.bbelements.com/please/showit/320/1/1/13/?typkodu=img&_idplan=69201
]]>
</Impression>
<Creatives>
<Creative id="23227072" AdID="23227072" sequence="1">
<Linear>
<Duration>00:00:15</Duration>
<AdParameters>
<![CDATA[
{"tag" : "http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=display&c=31&ai=23227072&dg=-1&sdg=-1&PluID=0&sessionId=8972504676093208509&filghtId=&preview=false&ta=-1&optout=optOut=0","skipoffset":"5"}
]]>
</AdParameters>
<TrackingEvents/>
<MediaFiles>
<MediaFile id="3022295" height="480" width="640" bitrate="" type="application/javascript" delivery="progressive" maintainAspectRatio="true" scalable="true" apiFramework="VPAID">
<![CDATA[ http://traffic.idmnet.pl/Wojtek/JSVpaid/vpaid.js ]]>
</MediaFile>
</MediaFiles>
</Linear>
</Creative>
<Creative id="23227072" AdID="23227072" sequence="1">
<CompanionAds/>
</Creative>
</Creatives>
</InLine>
</Ad>
</VAST>
```

I tested it on

https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/vastinspector
and gets only event contentPauseRequested

This is an example of the creation of

https://github.com/ryanthompson591/vpaidExamples/tree/master/nonLinear

Someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately when using the IMA SDK, you must use a creative on a secure protocol (https).

So your creative link will not work (http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=display&c=31&ai=23227072&dg=-1&sdg=-1&PluID=0&sessionId=8972504676093208509&filghtId=&preview=false&ta=-1&optout=optOut=0) - you need to serve it via a secure protocol (or use a proxy tool to trick the IMA!)